# My inverter produces over 240V AC, will it fry my equipment

Tags: voltage, inverter

I purchased a couple of batteries and decided to connect an inverter to invert the DC from the battery to AC. But before I connected any equipment I decided to test the voltage from the inverter, it is producing well over 240Volts AC.
Could this fry whatever equipment I connect to it or my equipment can handle the tolerance?
Below is a pic of the AC voltage being tested producing 262Volts 
[image: voltage]

Comment: put some load on the inverter.  most have poor regulation at v.low load

Comment: @JonRB I fear frying the devices I have i.e. laptop, mobile device and external hard drive. so the inverter's regulator is poor?

Comment: The inverter may not be outputting an accurate sine wave so that multimeter may not be giving an accurate reading. What does the meter on the inverter claim the voltage is? What happens to the voltage if you use it to power, say, a 60 W incandescent lamp?

Comment: You also have to ask how accurate the DVM is, and whether taht is affected by the inverter's waveform. Is is a "pure sinewave" inverter? If not, all bets are off as to what the DVM reading actually means.

Comment: Ask yourself if your multimeter has true RMS voltage readings, and whether you can find the datasheet or spec sheet or user manual for the inverter.

Comment: @Manny265 I was actually thinking of say... a lightbulb as oppose to something like laptop/phone etc... put a bit of load. A 100W incandescent would be good, a 18W CFL might be enough. Do you have a desk lamp handy?

Comment: Pls check the tolerance specs on load meet your supply tolerance , usually this is specified, 10% is normal, then drops to rated voltage at full load.

Comment: @AndrewMorton the inverter needle went into the red zone which is over 240V. it is not well calibrated. I put a lamp on it and the needle dropped to 220V and did not fry the lamp or anything

Comment: @BrianDrummond it is modified sine wave. which of the two is better between modified and pure?

Comment: Yeah, 262V with no load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from regulation, a modified sine wave inverter will likely give a somewhat higher voltage reading on a typical inexpensive RMS-modified average-reading multimeter than the RMS value. If you think about it, the sine wave is more "peaky" than a square-topped modified sine wave so the RMS value will be higher for the same average magnitude.

What matters for switching power supplies is mostly the peak value anyway.

If your charger brick is rated (say) 100~240VAC there will be an acceptable overvoltage outside of that range- 254VAC is within Europe specifications. If you are concerned an oscilloscope with an appropriate probe would answer the question definitively- peak should be less than about 360V.

Comment: Could there be cause for concern when supplying a SM PSU with something that has only a cursory resemblance to a sine wave? Those Solar Africa inverters *may not* be the very best that alibaba has to offer.

Comment: @AndrewMorton -- probably not in this day and age.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Most of the "modified sine wave" inverters are similar in nominal output waveform (3 level waveform), but yes, there are some shockingly (pun intended) shoddy products out there.